# Click EventHandler : Method Name Expected and other Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, event-handling

I am using framework version 2.0 (Cannot use 4.0) and the following way of assigning an Event Handler to Dynamically Created Button does not work:

```
deleteButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => DeleteAnswer(sender, e, toDelete);
```

**Error: 'lambda expression' cannot be used it is not part of the ISO - 2 C#**

So after some search, I tried this way:

```
deleteButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(DeleteAnswer(sender, e, toDelete));
```

**Error: Method Name Expected**

Then this way:

```
deleteButton.Click += DeleteAnswer(sender, e, toDelete);
```

**Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.EventHandler'**

---

This is a brief part of my code:

```
public partial class Question : System.Web.UI.Page
{

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            //Some Codes Here
           if(//Some Condition)
           {
                Button deleteButton = new Button();
                deleteButton.Click = //Event Handler Here
           }
     }

     protected void DeleteAnswer(object sender, EventArgs e, String answer)
     {
     }

}
```

What is the correct way to assign the Event Handler and also passing an argument?

**Update**

[image]

Comment: Just because you're using .NET 2 as a target doesn't mean you have to use C# 2 - it looks like you've got your build settings restricting you unnecessarily.

Comment: Why not just use the EventArgs argument to pass 'toDelete'

Comment: @JonSkeet Pardon me if I get you wrong, what should I do exactly? plus, I'm using 2.0 because the hosting server is set to 2.0 (cannot be changed).

Comment: @Ric can you give me a small example please?

Comment: @AliBassam: Where is the code being *compiled*? Because the error message you showed is one which indicates that you're using a later version of the C# compiler, but you're telling it to only accept C# 2 syntax.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using Visual Studio 2012, in the project proprieties, build, its targeted to framework 2.0.

Comment: @AliBassam: Under the Build tab, click on the Advanced button, and you should see a "Language Version" option - I suspect that's set to 2.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think I'm accessing the wrong Properties window and Build tab, because there's no Advanced option, please check the screenshot in my update.

Comment: @AliBassam: Ah, it's a different project type. I can't help you with that, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need the `sender` or `EventArgs` parameter, you can create a `delegate` which calls your method.

```
deleteButton.Click += delegate { DeleteAnswer(toDelete); };

protected void DeleteAnswer(string answer)
{
}
```

otherwise add the signature

```
deleteButton.Click += delegate(object s, EventArgs e) { DeleteAnswer(s, e, toDelete); };

protected void DeleteAnswer(object sender, EventArgs e, string answer)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a `delegate name` and `not its signature` -

```
deleteButton.Click+= ClickHandler;

protected void ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DeleteAnswer(sender, e, todelete);
}

protected void DeleteAnswer(object sender, EventArgs e, String answer)
{
}
```

Comment: **Error: No overload for 'DeleteAnswer' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'** - Also I need to pass an argument.

Comment: From first approach i can see is - you are calling button event handler and then call `DeleteAnswer` with `todelete` parameter. So, i have edited the answer down the same lines.

Comment: Your updated answer works without any Errors, but how will I be able to pass an argument from the moment I assign the Click Event? - in other words, with your current code, what is the value of todelete? This value must come from the Page Load method alongside the creation of the Button.